# My Hindu rope plant has yellow like pollen on some new shoots is this ok?

Tags: diagnosis

I have a beautiful variegated Hindu Rope.  It seems to have new buds. They are covered with a yellow pollen like substance. Is this ok?

Comment: can you add a photo please?